# Proving a that the arrival times of a Poisson process is uniformly distributed

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, poisson-process

I am stuck on this question for a very long time and I can't figure out the solution:

"Suppose $N_t$, $t\ge0$, is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and $N_t = 0$. $T_0$ and $T_1$ are the first and second arrival times of this Poisson process.

1. Prove that given $N_t=1$, $T_0$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,t]$, i.e. $P(T_0 \le t_o|N_t = 1) = \frac{t_o}{t}$.
2. Hence or otherwise, state the distribution of $T_1$ given $T_0 = t_o$ and $N_t=2$.

__

Edit: I can't seem to make what I type into MathJax so i'm typing here:

From $P(N_{t_0}=1∣N_t=1) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t_o} \lambda t_0}{e^{-\lambda t} \lambda t}$, of which there seems to be an extra $\frac{e^{t_o}}{e^{t}}$ in the solution.

Comment: What have you tried? After writing $P(T_0\le t_0 \mid N_t = 1) = P(N_{t_0} \ge 1\mid N_t = 1) = P(N_{t_0} = 1\mid N_t = 1)$, the first part is very easy to prove; the second comes from a similar argument.

Comment: @zhoraster i tried making it into a conditional probability, first, but never considered changing it into $P(N_t_0 \ge 1 | N_t = 1)$

Comment: So now you are able to solve, I hope?

Comment: @zhoraster not really...may I know what's the next step after what you showed? I'm stuck with an exponential term which can't cancel out

Comment: It cancels out. Write down everything you got.

Comment: @zhoraster I added the steps from what you provided previously in the original post, as the MathJax equation doesn't seem to display in the comments

Comment: It's clear now where is your mistake: $P(A\mid B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B)$, not $P(A)/P(B)$. If you write $P(\{N_{t_0} = 1\}\cap \{N_{t} = 1\}) = P(\{N_{t_0} = 1\}\cap \{N_{t} -N_{t_0} = 0\}) = \ldots$, then you will get the required answer.